# MySQLi query only one type of result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query all the results for only one type of message from the database:

Table:

```
ID    List    Content
1     8       This
2     8       That
3     9       Other
4     8       Last
```

There will be about 20,000 rows in this table, so I don't want to select them all and then sort through them if I don't have to. Basically, the `List` numbers will be changing, so I won't know what they are, but I only want to query results where `List` is the same.

It's a cron job script that will be removing these from the table after it's ran, so it doesn't matter what the `List` is, as long as each query returns all the same `List`.

What's the way of doing this straight from the MySQLi query without knowing what `List` is?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE List = 8
```

Comment: If i understand you correctly all you want to do is use a `WHERE` statement to filter results of a `SELECT` query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE List = '8';`

Comment: @Wobbles Correct, only I don't know what `List` will be.

Comment: if you dont know what list is then what data are you trying to get? How are you determining LIST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to select rows where `list` is duplicated.  To get the rows with the most duplication, you can use:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select list, count(*) as cnt
      from table
      group by list
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) tt
     on t.list = tt.list;
```

If you want any rows where `list` is duplicated, you can remove the `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `exists` to select all rows where another row with the same List value exists.

```
select * from mytable a
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable b
    where b.List = a.List
    and b.Id <> a.Id
)
```